# LibreNMS - clicking the "Config" tab on a device shows a server error

Tags: ubuntu, librenms

I have librenms installed from the master branch on github.

It seems to work mostly, but when I go to a device and try to click the "Config" tab, I get a server error.

After following the logging trail, I see in librenms.log that it is trying to connect to localhost:8888.  There is nothing listening on that port, so of course it fails to connect.  If something should be listening on 8888, how does it get started and what have I missed in my install?  I am using Apache as the front end for librenms, and I have haproxy sitting in front of that providing TLS.